# Small Angle Approximation for Simple Pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, oscillators, approximations

I am working on a simple pendulum problem. The $y$ direction is vertical and the $x$ direction is horizontal. Displacement in the $x$  direction is taken to be much less than the length of the string, $L$.

One of the small angle approximations given for this problem was $${\theta \over 2} \approx {y \over x}. $$ where $y$ and $x$ represents the coordinates of the pendulum.

Why is this true? One of the small angle approximations I know is $$\tan \theta \approx \theta, $$
giving 
$$\frac{x}{y}\approx\theta.$$

Where did the factor of two in the first equation come from?

[image]

Comment: It would help to know exactly where you are applying the small angle approximation.  I would guess to Newton's laws of motion, right?

Comment: Where is your origin?  That matters a lot too.

Comment: $sin(\theta/2)=\theta/2-1/3!((\theta)/2)^3+....$  
so for  small angles like  6     
1/3!((\theta)/2)^3=1.9*10^-4

Comment: Is this the original diagram that was used?  Maybe, in the original diagram, theta, y, and x were defined differently?

Comment: If you look carefully the geometric scheme you should realize that, with the notation uset there, $tan \theta = y/x$. Of course, for small angles $tan \theta$ and $\theta$ can be identified.

Comment: The only possibility I see for $\theta/2$ is if the angle $\theta$ corresponds to the total angular excursion of the pendulum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the origin is not P, but the point where the pendulum intersects the vertical axis. As a result the coordinates are:

$x = L \sin(\theta)$

$y = L - L \cos(\theta)$

Which gives us:

$\frac{y}{x} = \frac{1 - \cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} = \tan(\frac{\theta}{2}) \approx \frac{\theta}{2}$

Another way of finding the same result is to calculate (geometrically) the angle between the pendulum, the origin, and the horizontal axis: it is equal to $\frac{\theta}{2}$.